# Submit under edit() of object to create() under different object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, input

Ruby on Rails 3

My edit page for my Reseller object has a button to submit the user_id of a selected user. The form POSTs the correct user_id but is using the edit() method for the reseller_controller. All I want it to do is create a new record under the Certificate table with the POSTed user_id. I am confused though since the app seems to reference the create() method for the certificates_controller. It does not do anything except send the POST. What am I missing?

My model:

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :attend, :pass, :user_id
validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

My reseller_controller with the edit()

```
def edit
  @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  @trained.save
end
```

My certificate_controller with create()

```
def create
  @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  @trained.save
end
```

My edit.html.erb with the button

```
<%= form_for(@trained) do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@current_users.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  <%= f.submit "Trained", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the log of when I click button:

```
Started POST "/certificates" for 50.241.102.234 at 2013-12-20 10:54:43 -0800
Processing by CertificatesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xYUdeMjkxa1b0AhNTKJi9sDbSPo9MbwMMVPrV7cgpyo=", "certificate"=>{"user_id"=>"16"}, "commit"=>"Trained"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit controller is expected to return the existing instance, you are returning a new instance.

```
def edit
  @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  @trained.save
end
```

should be

```
def edit
  @trained = Certificate.find(params[:id])
end
```

The edit action will post to an update action

```
def update
  @trained = Certificate.find(params[:id])
  @trained.update_attributes(params[:certificate])
end
```

`form_for(@trained)` behaves in two different ways depending whether you are passing a new record or not. If the record is new it `POST /create`, if the record is persisting `PUT /update`.

Please note that my code is skipping all the validations and error management.

Comment: The update method should be in my certificates_controller right?

Comment: The certificate record has to be created if it does not exist though. And right now none of the users have a certificate record associated with it so I need to create a new one the first time.

Comment: You have a lot of confusion about how Rails works. By default, the `new` action is expected to send to `create`, `edit` to `update`. Of course you can customize it, but you should have some knowledge of how Rails works internally.